# Django ModelForm widget and non-widget field ordering

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I have a django (1.11.9) ModelForm for events with times (start and end). When I display it to the user in a template I want `last_field` to be the last field in the form at the bottom:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

    start = forms.DateTimeField(
        label="Start time (in event's local time)",
        required=False,
        input_formats=[dt]
    )

    end = forms.DateTimeField(
        label="End time (in event's local time)",
        required=False,
        input_formats=[dt]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
         'name', 'flexibility', 'timezone', 
         'date_start', 'date_end', 'last_field', 
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['date_start'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields['date_end'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

        i = kwargs.get('instance')
        tz = pytz.timezone(i.timezone) if i and i.timezone else None
        if i and i.flexibility == Event.FLEXIBILITY_ONTIME and tz:
            self.fields['start'].initial = i.date_start.astimezone(tz).strftime(self.dt) if i.date_start else None
            self.fields['end'].initial = i.date_end.astimezone(tz).strftime(self.dt) if i.date_end else None

        else:
            self.fields['start'].initial = None
            self.fields['end'].initial = None
```

however, even explicitly setting `'last_field'` at the end of the `fields = []` array (per docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-order-of-fields), the `start` and `end` widget fields in the form render below it out of the set field order.

is there a way to override the widgets to force the ordering of the fields? thanks

Comment: It's not a perfect solution, but have you tried defining the `last_field` explicitly after `end` on EventForm?

Comment: re-ordering the model fields doesn't change it `start` (`date_start`) and `end` (`date_end`) still render last in the form and i'm unclear what's forcing the widgets to the end of the form (or how to over ride that ordering).

Comment: You'd have to add some breakpoints in Django to see how the forms work. Otherwise your best bet is to customize the template itself.